# Find the integral: $\int ( 4x -1 +3 \sqrt{x})\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, solution-verification

I have to find the following integral:

$$\int ( 4x -1 +3 \sqrt{x})\mathrm{d}x$$

My answer is $2x^2 -\ 1x + \frac{2\sqrt{27}}{3}$. Am I right?

Comment: Compute the derivative of your answer and check if it is identical to the integrand. This is something you always must do.

Comment: 1. You are missing the constant of integration. 2. If you differentiate it do you get the integrand back?

Comment: The third term I am confused as to how to solve. The second was a silly mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int \left( 4x -1 +3 \sqrt{x}\right) dx$$
$$=4\int x\ dx-\int dx +3\int x^{\frac12} dx$$
$$=\frac{4x^2}{2}-x + \frac{3x^{\frac32}}{\frac32}+C$$
$$=2x^2-x + 2x^{\frac32}+C$$
Here's how we can verify this answer
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left[ 2x^2-x + 2x^{\frac32}+C \right] $$
$$ =\frac{d}{dx}\left[2x^2\right] -\frac{d}{dx}[x]+ \frac{d}{dx}\left[2x^{\frac32} \right]+\frac{d}{dx}[C]$$
$$ =2\cdot 2x-1+ \frac{2\cdot 3x^{\frac12}}{2} +0$$
$$=4x-1+3x^{\frac12}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\bf{My \; Solution::}$  $\displaystyle \int (4x-1+3\sqrt{x})dx = 4\int xdx - \int 1 dx+3\int x^{\frac{1}{2}}dx = 4\cdot \frac{x^2}{2}-x+3\cdot \frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}}+\mathcal{C}$

Above we have used the formula $\displaystyle \int x^ndx = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+\mathcal{C}\;,$ Where $n\neq -1$

Comment: so the final answer is 2x^2 - 1x + 2x^3/2 + C ?

Comment: @Cetshwayo  yes. you can write $1\cdot x$ as $x$

Answer (score -1):

Your answer is not correct. If you integrate term by term, you have:

\begin{align}
&\int ( 4x -1 +3 \sqrt{x})\mathrm{d}x \\
&\implies \int 4x \mathrm{d}x - \int 1 \mathrm{d}x+\int 3\sqrt{x} \mathrm{d}x \\
&\implies 2x^2 - x + 2x^\frac{3}{2} + C
\end{align}

If you have further questions, let me know!

Comment: the last term can also be written as 2x^ 3/2?

Comment: @Jeel Your last term, as the OP notes in the comment above, is incorrect. It should be $$3\cdot \frac{x^{3/2}}{\frac 32} = 2x^{3/2}$$

Comment: Ha! Thanks for pointing that out. That's a little ironic. @Cetshwayo I apologize if I mislead you.